# Check if a mule flow is not executing

Tags: mule

Can i check whether a mule flow is stoppable. How do i check if a mule flow is not executing.

```
Flow flow = muleEventContext.getMuleContext().getRegistry().lookupObject(flowName);

//Before stopping the flow need to check if flow is not executing

//Stop the flow

flow.stop();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the statistics of each flow:

```
FlowConstruct flow = muleContext.getRegistry().lookupFlowConstruct(flowName);
FlowConstructStatistics fs = flow.getStatistics();
```

http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.mule/mule-core/3.4.0/org/mule/management/stats/FlowConstructStatistics.java#FlowConstructStatistics

Here you can get the amount of processed events, get the average queue size etc. This information might help you.

Comment: Ryan  i looked at the javadoc for FlowConstructStatistics i dont see  a method to check if the flow has completed executing.Can you tell me how i can check this.